# Implementing integration in Python and vectorize operation

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-2.7, vectorization

I want to implement these integrals in Python
Where each of the integrals variables are list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVUIl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR2Pg.png)

Here is my trial to write the content of each integrals before performing it, i need to check weather i am following the write way in writing the vectorize operations between the lists

```
I1 = ([i / j for i, j in zip(dx, br)])
    I2 = ([1 / np.square(br)])
    I4 = ([i / j for i, j in zip(dx, (i**3 for i in br))]+[i / j for i, j in zip((i * j for i, j in zip(2*dx,qs)), br)])

    H = ((i * j for i, j in zip(ga,np.square(dx)))+ (2 * i * j * l for i, j, l  in zip(al, dx,dp)) +  (i * j for i, j, l  in zip(be,np.square(dp)) ) )
    I5 = ([i / j for i, j in zip(H, numpy.linalg.norm(i**3 for i in br) )])
```

I jot the error for the H equation

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'
```

My second question is how to perform an integration over closed loop for a one array ?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you are using [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression). This is a simple example that reproduces your problem because you can't add generators:

```
>>> g = (i**2 for i in [1,2,3])
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f6d03b77660>
>>> g + g
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'
```

You could use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead because you can add (concatenate) lists:

```
>>> g = [i**2 for i in [1,2,3]]
>>> g
[1, 4, 9]
>>> g + g
[1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9]
```

But there are other problems. Your code is not vectorized, and you should take advantage of Numpy vectorization. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dx = np.array([1. ,2. ,3.])
>>> br = np.array([4., 5., 6.])

>>> I1 = ([i / j for i, j in zip(dx, br)])   # Your version
>>> I1
[0.25, 0.4, 0.5]

>>> I1 = dx / br          # Fast vectorized Numpy operation
>>> I1
>>> array([0.25, 0.4 , 0.5 ])
```

Also, if you are performing an integration, you need to add all the values. For example, with your code:

```
>>> qs = np.array([7., 8., 9.])
>>> I4 = [i / j for i, j in zip(dx, (i ** 3 for i in br))] + \
         [i / j for i, j in zip((i * j for i, j in zip(2 * dx, qs)), br)]
>>> sum(I4)
18.94551388888889
```

Or using Numpy:

```
>>> I4 = dx / br * (br**-2 + 2 * qs)
>>> I4.sum()
18.94551388888889
```

I've just converted some of your code into a form that's faster and easier to write. But I'm not checking whether your code really reflects the integrals in the linked image.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried to use I2 = br**-2
but i got an error " unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'"

Comment: That's because your `br` is a list, not a numpy array.
Check my example declaration of `br`.

Comment: The integration has an integration element ds where s is an array containing every point in a circle how can i calculate ds ? the arrays that i want to integrate are also dependent on s . I edited the post with a picture

Comment: In a numerical integration you convert a infinitesimal change in s (ds) into a small change of s (Δs), which is only the difference between consecutive values of s.

Comment: But using the "rectangular rule" will most likely lead to invalid results. There are plenty of techniques for [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) and you can find some of them implemented in [scipy.integrate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html).